# Moving navbar to top after hiding header in mobile view bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, header, navbar

Can you help me to solve this problem using bootstrap html css ? I tried  position fixed, absolute and static but it did not work.

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have your code, I guess you have 2 divs `.header` and `.navbar`.

You can use the `d-lg-none` Bootstrap class for example to hide your header on screen with a width >= 992px.

(click on "full page" to see the orange part disapear)

[Available Bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/)

[Bootstrap display property](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/)

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .d-lg-none {
    display: none!important;
  }
}


body{
  margin: 0;
}
div{
  height: 30px;
}
.header{
  background-color: orange;
}
.navbar{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header d-lg-none"></div>
<div class="navbar"></div>
```